# Linking separate header and class definition files to a main function file - G++ returns "undefined reference to" overloaded constructors

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compilation, g++

I have 5 files that I'm trying to link together; 2 header files with class declarations, 2 cpp files with Class definitions, and 1 file with the main method

**Header File 1: city.h**

```
#ifndef CITY_H
#define CITY_H

class City
{
// Class header code
}
#endif
```

**Definition File 1: city.cpp**

```
#include "City.h
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef CITY_H
#define CITY_H
//Class definition code
#endif
```

This is where I'm getting an error when compiling

**Header File 2: hash.h**

```
#include "City.h
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef CITY_H
#define CITY_H
//Class definition code
#endif
```

**Definition File 2: hash.h**

```
#include "Hash.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef HASH_H
#define HASH_H
//Class definition
#endif
```

**.cpp File with Main Method**

```
#include "Hash.cpp"
#include "City.cpp"

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int size;
    Hash* table = new Hash(size);

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile with g++ I get the following error:

```
/tmp/ccXGXFpg.o: In function 'main':
Project1.cpp:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to 'Hash::Hash(int)'
collect2: error: 1d returned 1 exit status
```

I'm really not sure what's wrong. The constructor for Hash is overloaded so there is a Hash::Hash() and Hash::Hash(int) definition. I've been trying to figure it out but I'm beat. Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This includes but isn't limited to: **your code** and how you call the compiler

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Unrelated: including cpp files is a bad, bad idea. Unlikely to be related to your current problem, but it often results in duplicate definitions as everything in City.cpp and Hash.cpp is now duplicated in the main cpp. Compiling City.cpp and Hash.cpp and linking them with the main cpp, what you are supposed to do with cpp files, will result in 2 copies of everything in City.cpp and Hash.cpp being found twice. Include headers. Compile and link cpp files.

Comment: Anyway, your actual problem cannot be conclusively solved with the information provided. Voting to close.

Comment: Remove `#ifndef` , `#define` and `#undef` directives from `.cpp` files.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `#ifndef` directive in *.cpp* file. I suppose your *hash.h* file has content

```
#include "City.h
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef HASH_H
#define HASH_H
//Class definition code
#endif
```

so when *hash.cpp* file is compiled, the code of which is

```
#include "Hash.h"   // [1]
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef HASH_H   // [2]
#define HASH_H
//Class definition
hash::hash () {
     // ctor definition
}
#endif
```

in *[1]* line content of header file was included to *.cpp* file, and `HASH_H` macro was defined. In [2] line `#ifndef` directive checks whether `HASH_H` is defined, if so, all definitions of your hash class members are ignored and you get *undefined reference* error when linker works.

If you compile *main.cpp*, *hash.cpp* and *city.cpp* separately, in *main.cpp* you should put

```
#include "city.h"
#include "hash.h"
```

instead of

```
#include "city.cpp"
#include "hash.cpp"
```

without this you will get multiple definitions error.